# How to interpolate (polynomial) a matrix with matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, interpolation

I would like to know how to do polynomial interpolation on a matrix. I have a feeling that it involves the Vandermonde matrix, but that's about it.

I don't want to use a computer algorithm to do it, either. I would like to do it with as much linear algebra as possible.

For example, here is my solution for using linear interpolation using matrix multiplication.

Consider the 2x3 matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\4&5&6 \end{bmatrix}$

If $L=\begin{bmatrix}
    1&         0\\
    0.5&    0.5\\
         0&    1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $R=\begin{bmatrix}
    1&    0.5&         0&         0&         0\\
         0&    0.5&    1&    0.5&         0\\
         0&         0&         0&    0.5&    1
\end{bmatrix}$

then the linear interpolation of $A_{2x3}$ is

$(LAR)_{3x5}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1.0000&    1.5000&    2.0000&    2.5000&    3.0000\\
    2.5000&    3.0000&    3.5000&    4.0000&    4.5000\\
    4.0000&    4.5000&    5.0000&    5.5000&    6.0000
\end{bmatrix}$

This can easily be generalized to any mxn matrix. Its linear interpolation is a (2m-1)x(2n-1) matrix. It's also easy to add multiple interpolated columns/rows. No messy for loops.

How can I accomplish polynomial interpolation using matrix multiplication? (Vandermonde?)

Bonus question: none of the algorithms for linear interpolation I came across use matrix multiplication. I would think that this would be more efficient. I think GPUs are basically design to calculate things this way. Any ideas why?

Thanks :D

Comment: Re last paragraph: For larger $A$, the matrices $L$ and $R$ are very sparse, making general matrix multiplication less efficient

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's an excellent point. Thank you.